# How do I remove "Hangouts Remote Desktop" from Google hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts

I see somebody has asked how to remove a specific app from Google Hangouts (sidebar) but unfortunately the directions are specific to their app. In my case, every time I start a hangouts video call, "Hangouts Remote Desktop" pops up with an error message that says it's been discontinued and I should use Chrome Remote Desktop instead for screen sharing. The thing is, they don't tell me how to remove it! All I can do is hover over the icon on my hangouts video call sidebar and "x" out of it for that particular video call. Next time I start a video call, the Hangouts Remote Assistance icon is back, and so is the annoying error message! Google has an article with a title that indicates it will tell me how to remove an app from Hangouts, but it doesn't! It simply says how to add one. Please help!? It's getting really frustrating....  Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en whether this helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you're browsing from Chrome (and Hangouts is open) you'll see a little icon for Hangouts on the top right corner next to the menu button. Right click on it and there's an option to remove!

Comment: Welcome to the Web Applications - Stack Exchange site. Please take the [tour](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn the ropes.

Comment: Also you could take a look to [Add or remove an app in Hangouts - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/2539435?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Steps to remove the Google Hangouts App.

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Type chrome://apps in the address bar.
3. Right click on Google Hangouts app, and select Remove from Chrome.